# Appending two lists into one - python

Tags: python, list, append

The below is the code what I have so far.

```
rawcountries =[]
countries = []
cursor1 = collection.find({})
cursor2 = collection.find({})
for document1 in cursor1:
    finding1 = str(document1['rawCountry'])
    edited = finding1 + ":"
print(edited)
rawcountries.append(edited)
for document2 in cursor2:
    finding2 = document2['country']
    countries.append(finding2)
```

Now in `print rawcountries` list, I have:

```
['Jakarta (Lippo):', 'Petaling Jaya (Empire City):', 'Singapore (Cecil `Court):', 'Singapore (Cecil Court):', 'Singapore (Marina One):', 'Singapore (Marina One):', 'Jakarta (Lippo):', 'Singapore (Cecil Court):', 'Singapore (Marina One):', 'Bangalore (Salarpuria Adonis):',....`
```

Next in `print countries` list, I have:

```
[u'ID', None, u'SG', u'SG', u'SG', u'SG', u'ID', None, u'SG', None, u'ID', u'SG', u'SG', u'SG', u'SG', u'SG', u'SG', u'MY', u'MY', u'US', u'ID', u'SG', u'ID', None, u'US', None, None, None, u'US', u'MM', u'KH',
```

I want to append both lists into a format like below:

```
[ "Jakarta (Lippo):ID" , "Petaling Jaya (Empire City): None ", "Singapore (Cecil `Court): SG ", ........."]
```

So, the question is how can i do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know that the lists are the same length you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
result = [r+str(c) for (rc,c) in zip(rawcountries, countries)]
```